# How to make an Object creation decoupled from its signature

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project and I am currently struggling with a problem. My Angular application depends on a specific object that I initialize in one of my classes. In my case, this object can have different attributes/fields depending on the configurations of the project. The configurations CAN change during runtime, so therefore the object can be different in each configuration. The problem is, that I do not want to couple the object creation to one specific configuration. I want to be able to set this dynamically.

The object itself:

```
port interface Stages {
  Installation: string;
  Migration: string;

  [key: string]: any;
}
```

The object I want to instantiate:

```
Stages: {
  Installation: 'false',
  Migration: 'false',
  ...
}
```

How can I decouple the instantiation of the object so that my implementation does not care which attribute or field is changed into false?

Comment: You mean `type Stages = { Installation: string; Migration: string } & { [k: string]: any }`?

Comment: Hey @Nick. No, because then my implementation would still depend on the attributes "Installation" and "Migration".

Comment: Do you mean `'false'` or `false`? As shown in your question, I can't see where the problem lies.

Comment: @Guusda If you don't want it to depends on anything just declare it this way: `type Stages = { [k: string]: any }` or `type Stages = Record<string, any>`

Comment: Hey @WillAlexander. I mean 'false', it should be a string attribute. The values of the attributes are in this case not important. It is about the attributes themselves. 

Imagine that in a different instance of my application a completely different configuration exist - in this configuration there would be no attributes called "Installation", and "Migration". In this case there would be "Deinstallation" and "Startup". My problem is that I would to change the source code every single time depending on the configuration.

Comment: Do you have a set list of possible attributes?

Comment: @WillAlexander Not necessarily, no.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? This just looks like an object where the keys and values are strings.